# truth table for D flip flop with control variables x and y

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, design, flipflop, counter

So I need to build a counter with D Flip-Flop and 2 control variables x and y.

XY=00 --> 0-3-2-1-0;
XY=01 --> 0-1-2-3-0;
XY=10 --> 0-2-3-1-0;
XY=11 --> 0-1-3-2-0.

How should I make the truth table? Should I put for every sequence for x and y the given controls(00,01,10,11) or I need to put for x and y 0 an 1 in order?

Comment: I'm trying to picture this in my mind. Where are these control variables? Pictures are very helpful on this website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a K-map with control and current state as your axis. From that you can derive the next state. 
$$
\begin{array}{lc|cccc} \
&& \rlap{AB_\text{(current state)}} \\
   &    & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\\hline
XY & 00 & \color{blue}{1}\color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{0}\color{red}{0} & \color{blue}{1}\color{red}{0} & \color{blue}{0}\color{red}{1} \\
   & 01 & \color{blue}{0}\color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{1}\color{red}{0} & \color{blue}{0}\color{red}{0} & \color{blue}{1}\color{red}{1} \\
   & 11 & \color{blue}{0}\color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{1}\color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{1}\color{red}{0} & \color{blue}{0}\color{red}{0} \\
   & 10 & \color{blue}{1}\color{red}{0} & \color{blue}{0}\color{red}{0} & \color{blue}{0}\color{red}{1} & \color{blue}{1}\color{red}{1} \\
\end{array}
\\
\begin{align}
\color{blue}{a}_\text{(next state)} & = \bar{Y}\bar{A}\bar{B} + Y\bar{A}B + \bar{X}\bar{Y}AB + \cdots_\color{blue}{\text{(other blue groupings)}} \\
\color{red}{b}_\text{(next state)} & = XY\bar{A} + X\bar{Y}A + \cdots_\color{red}{\text{(other red groupings)}} \\
\end{align}
$$

**Note**: To ensure I'm not doing your homework, the equations are *intentionally* incomplete and the k-map entries may/may-not be accurate. If finding the groups from from a double variable is challenging, split into seperate k-maps (one for red entries, the other blue).